# Rounded Oil Drain Plug Dodge RAM

Tags: oil, dodge

I am changing the oil on a 07 Dodge Ram 1500 with a manual transmission.  First surprise was the filter that required a wrench to take off. Second is the oil drain bolt is skipping a lot, I can't get a ratchet on it. II used a box end 13mm on a 14mm bolt and it stayed pretty tight but couldn't get it off, it just keeps going. Used a hammer on the box end to impact it, still no budge. Last ditch attempt was pliers and they didn't work.

Anyway to change the oil without that drain plug? Or how can I take that plug off. I still has some thread on the bolt but not much. It hasn't even budged.

Answer (score 5):

From your description it is a bit unclear what the problem with the drain plug bolt is. I'm assuming that the hex head on the bolt has become rounded, and as a result your wrenches and sockets are slipping on the bolt head, preventing you from removing the drain plug.

If this is the case, you can try welding another nut or bolt onto the rounded drain plug, then using a wrench on the newly welded nut to remove the drain plug. As a bonus, often the rapid heating and cooling from the welding operation will break free seized or rusted threads, so less torque may be required to remove the bolt after the welding operation.

[image]

If you don't have access to a welder, you can remove and replace the entire oil pan (first choice, if you can afford the new oil pan).

Or you can drill out the stuck drain plug and use a thread repair kit (e.g. [heli-coil](http://www.helicoil.in/), or [threaded bushing](http://www.timesert.com/html/drainplug.html)) to install a new drain plug. In this case, you'll make some metal chips in the drilling operation, and you'll want to make sure that you clean all of these chips from the oil pan before adding new oil and starting the vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

mac has given a pretty comprehensive coverage of what you can do with your drain plug to remove it. The only thing I would add is to try a plumbers Stilsons on what ever protrusion of the sump plug remains. They grip tighter the more you lever on them to undo anything.